# Angular ng-repeat e $sce.trustAsHtml

Tags: angularjs

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde vai PHP em PDO, Angular com o crud ficando mais rápido e pegando a lista que vem do banco de dados MySQL, a versão do AngularJS é v1.5.8.

Então eu to travado numa parte  `$sce.trustAsHtml` e já olhei [esse site](http://www.developmentshack.com/angularjs-ng-bind-html-and-sce-trustashtml) como referência. É basicamente isso o que quero mas não funciona. Também vi [este exemplo](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AngularJS-sce-trustAsHtml-example.aspx) que é em C# mas não tem problema.

Código é aquele sem `ng-repeat` só que é simples, preciso que a lista de dados que vem da base com código HTML seja convertido e não apresente `<b>oi</b>` e sim **oi**.

Vou exemplificar melhor:  a lista vem da base de dados e converte para JSON ficando:

```
{ nome: `<b>andré</b>`' }
```

Só que apresenta na View no HTML `<b>andré</b>`

meu código no js controller ficou assim:

```
var app = angular.module('myAngularApp',[]);   
app.controller('Controller',function($scope, $http, $sce){

$scope.getOldFour = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'Controller/noticias-controller/read.php'           
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            response.data[i].records = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data[i].records);
        }


        $scope.noticiasFour = response.data;
        //$scope.noticiasFour = response.data.records;
    });
  }    
});
```

e pelo que vi no html tenho que usar essa tag **ng-bind-html**

Esse é meu HTML:

```
<ul class="news_tab" ng-init="getOldFour()">
  <li ng-repeat="OldFour in noticiasFour">                                                                
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left">
        <a class="news_img" href="#">
          <img class="media-object" src="App_Imagens/Noticias/Teste.jpg" alt="img">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <div ng-bind-html="noticiasFourr"></div>
        <a href="#" ng-bind-html="">{{OldFour.descricao}}</a>
        <span class="feed_date">{{OldFour.data_postagem}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Já tentei `<a href="#" ng-bind-html="OldFour.descricao"></a>` e nada

No PHP no controller que vai realizar o read e fazer a lista já tentei também `html_entity_decode()` e não funcionou também.

Para enviar para a base de dados já utilizei de `htmlentities()` deixando a string dentro do bd maior, ao invés de ir `<b></b>`

Já tentei de todas as formas e não funciona, já procurei em vários sites, será que alguém tem uma solução? Uma experiência parecida com resolução ?

Comment: Se nao me engano o ng-bind-html se usa assim: `<a href="#" ng-bind-html="OldFour.descricao"></a>` ou so foi algum teste que 'sobrou'?

Comment: André, o problema tá em **mostrar o HTML interpretado na view** ou em **salvar como HTML no banco de dados**? Sua pergunta tá completamente confusa.

Comment: Oi Neuber Oliveira eu não entendi sua pergunta.  jbueno é o mostrar o HTML interpretado na view

Comment: Um bom exemplo do que tento fazer é dizer que o usuario insere uma noticia e esse textarea leva de bootstrap-wysiwyg ele usa essa tecnologia e vai para a base de dados <a>andre</a>  mas quando volta ele não muda e faz um link e sim aparece no html <a>andre</a>, já fiz de tudo para o $sce.trustAsHtml() me obedecer mas não consigo, não sei se estou colocando no lugar errado ou esquecendo algo.

Comment: @AndréAranda Postei uma resposta.

Comment: @jbueno vi sua postagem e respondi, o problema é que não consegui chegar a solução, precisava tirar mais umas duvidas com você de angular

Comment: Coloca um exemplo do seu `JSON` que está retornando pra podermos ter uma idéia. Pode copiar e colar um retorno qualquer.

Answer (score 1):

Não dá pra entender bem o seu problema, mas é bem fácil de fazer o que você precisa.

Antes de tudo é necessário ter o módulo `ngSanitize` referenciado, depois é só usar a diretiva `ng-bind-html` com o HTML que precisa ser mostrado.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

angular.module('app').controller('mainController', mainControllerFn);

function mainControllerFn(){
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.bindHtml = '<b>Andre</b>';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
    {{mainCtrl.bindHtml}}
        
    <div ng-bind-html="mainCtrl.bindHtml">
      
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi, tentei utilizar aqui o angular-sanitize mas não resolveu. No meu quando tentei aplicar isso ao ng-repeat deu esse erro Error: [$sce:itype] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$sce/itype?p0=html .  Se eu tirar o  $sce.trustAsHtml() do $scope.noticiasFour = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.records); ele volta a funcionar só que apresenta <b></b> no html que é o que eu não quero.

Comment: Acho que não estou sabendo qual é a forma correta de se aplicar $sce.trustAsHtml()  nesse meu comando $scope.noticiasFour = response.data.records; que funciona e trás da base de dados.

Comment: Jovem, seguinte. Como é o retorno do seu backend e o que você precisa fazer com ele? Seu código tá fazendo umas coisas meio sem noção.

Comment: tah não, eu vou postar aqui o código do backend para facilitar. Vou separar em MVC

Comment: Nãããão, não precisa do código do backend. Você só precisa explicar o que quer fazer e como é o retorno.